# AWS API Gateway- Offset-Limit

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am working on a Warehouse Management System using AWS services. We are using API Gateway. What is the best way to utilize offset-limit for query searches? Through API Gateway?

We want to limit what we return from the search as so using the GUI api gateway

```
components:
  parameters:
    includeDeleted:
      in: query
      name: includeDeleted
      description: Whether or not to include soft deleted items in result.
      explode: true
      required: false
      style: form
      schema:
        default: false
        type: boolean
    offset:
      description: Number of items to skip before returning the results.
      explode: true
      in: query
      name: offset
      required: false
      schema:
        default: 0
        format: int32
        minimum: 0
        type: number
      style: form
    limit:
      description: Maximum number of items to return.
      explode: true
      in: query
      name: limit
      required: false
      schema:
        default: 100
        format: int32
        maximum: 100
        minimum: 1
        type: number
      style: form
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage plan than can specify who can assess associated API stages with specified request limits and quotas. see the following [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/usage-plan/)

Comment: i edited my response. How do i set it up using the GUI